# Cross Domain AJAX preflighting failing Origin check

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

This doesn't seem to work:

```
$.ajax({
    url:      "http://localhost:3000/foo.json",
    data:     { foo: 'bar' },
    headers:  { 'HTTP_X_CUSTOMHEADER': 'foobar' },
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
});
```

When I run it on jsfiddle, an `OPTIONS` request (according to the Chrome debug tools) fires off that looks like this:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: Origin, HTTP_X_CUSTOMHEADER, Accept
Access-Control-Request-Method:  GET
Origin:                         http://fiddle.jshell.net
```

And then (according to the Chrome debug tools) my local server returns the following headers:

*(manually reformatted for readability)*

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:     HTTP_X_CUSTOMHEADER
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:     GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:      http://fiddle.jshell.net
Access-Control-Max-Age:           10

Cache-Control:                    no-cache
Connection:                       Keep-Alive
Content-Length:                   1
Content-Type:                     text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:                             Wed, 14 Sep 2011 22:42:28 GMT
Server:                           WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.8.7/2010-01-10)
X-Runtime:                        2
```

And then in the console I get an error message like this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/foo.json?foo=bar.
Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

But the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header appears identical to when my server responded with to the preflight request.  So what piece am I missing here of this puzzle?

Comment: What do the headers from the outgoing request look like? They should include an [Origin:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control) header. However, I believe the browser [always appends it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control#Origin).

Comment: Updated the question with the headers from the options request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OHHHHH, ok I figured this out, finally...

Apparently the preflight `OPTIONS` response headers arent the only place that needs them.  You need to include those headers on the response for the actual content as well.  I only had these headers coming down on the preflight, thinking that was the only "ticket" needed.

So I added the same headers to the GET request for the actual asset and everything works great now.  I guess I missed that in the docs.

Comment: Could you go into more detail?  I'm stuck in CORS hell: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318436/https-access-control-allow-origin-not-working-no-matter-what-with-php-5-3-apac

Comment: Can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41952995/response-status-is-0-in-jquery-ajax?noredirect=1#comment71099392_41952995??

Answer (score 1):

You need to include Origin in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers section, since Origin is not considered a simple header (IMO, the spec should include Origin in the list of simple headers).

Comment: I changed the OPTIONS response headers to include `Access-Control-Allow-Headers:HTTP_X_CUSTOMHEADER, Origin, Accept` but it didn't change anything.