# Response status is '0' in jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using a jquery ajax for storing a data in the database. I call a service through a url and send data to it in the following way:

```
$.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://192.168.250.118:8080/rest_service/rest/user",
                        data: JSON.stringify({ "loginName": "tsample@gmail.com", "mobile": "1234567890" }),
                        async: false,
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        crossDomain: true,
                        success: function(data){
                            alert("success");
                        },
                        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                            console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
                            console.log(textStatus);
                            console.log(errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
```

When I execute this, I get this error:

```
{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

This is what I get when I look for errors in network:

[image]

But, if I try using postman, the data is getting stored and I get `200OK` response. What's wrong with the above code? What should I change?

Comment: Change alert(response.status) to console.log(response) and let the browser tell you the error. Should you then still need help, post the error

Comment: 0 is success or error alert ?

Comment: read old  so question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000609/jquery-ajax-status-code-0

Comment: BTW: You can use the network tab of the dev tools in modern browsers to directly look at the response from your rest API.

Comment: @FreddySidauruk: error alert.

Comment: @baao: this is what I get: `Object { readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: .ajax/x.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/x.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/x.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/x.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/x.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/x.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always: .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), 10 more… }`

Comment: @SSS try `console.log(JSON.stringify(response));` it'll probably be more readable. Also be aware that the "error" callback has two other parameters: textStatus and errorThrown, which are both strings - see the docs at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Again, post the error. Edit your question and add it. What you have commented is not the error, but the response object.

Comment: And put the output in a code block in your question, not as a comment please.

Comment: Is there any CORS related error in the console? Something similar to  `Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Comment: @Developer: I don't think so. That is why I've provided `crossDomain: true`.

Comment: setting `crossDomain: true` doesn't mean you can escape CORS issue. The response headers should have valid CORS headers to get this working. If you dont have CORS related error in network tab/console, then this might be some other issue.

Comment: @Developer: It doesn't show anything. I get the above mentioned error only. Even in network it doesn't show CORS error thing.

Comment: try `data: JSON.stringify({ "loginName": "tsample@gmail.com", "mobile": "1234567890" })`. Also get ther entire error details - `error: function(  jqXHR,  textStatus,  errorThrown ){}` and check whether you have any usable info in `errorThrown`

Comment: Content-Type should be "application/json", but in your request its going as form-urlencoded. try `data: JSON.stringify({ "loginName": "tsample@gmail.com", "mobile": "1234567890" })` and set `contentType:"application/json" in the ajax call.

Comment: @Developer: I tried as how you told. But, same result. See the above edited code.

Comment: still you havnt changed the data - `data: JSON.stringify({ "loginName": "tsample@gmail.com", "mobile": "1234567890" })`

Comment: @Developer: Sorry didn't show that. Check it out now

Comment: How does your network tab values look now? Please update that as well. Also in your code its `http` but in network tab its `https` - is that a typo?

Comment: @Developer: Have updated that too.

Comment: voila...now you got the CORS issue I guess :)

Comment: @Developer: How do you say that?

Comment: I won't say it threw error, but CORS has triggered - check the preflight `OPTIONS` request being sent

Comment: Which means the call is made fine now and your original issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Stringify the data before sending - `data: JSON.stringify({ "loginName": "tsample@gmail.com", "mobile": "1234567890" })` amd `contentType:"application/json"`